# Django Generic Relation while manually selecting databases

Tags: python, django

I have this models in `project1` which uses [genericrelation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#reverse-generic-relations),

```
class Sale(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    invoice = GenericRelation('Invoice')

class Invoice(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

In project1 if I do,

```
>>>sale = Sale.objects.all()
>>>sale[0].invoice.all()
[<Invoice: 155>]
```

I have collected all models in an app under `project2` using [`inspectdb`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/django-admin/#inspectdb) command. 
But if I repeat same in other `project2`. I'm using [`using`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/multi-db/#manually-selecting-a-database) key word to manually select the database, I get the error.

Models.py contains Invoice model as,

```
class AppInvoice(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)  # AutoField?

    object_id = models.IntegerField()
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(DjangoContentType)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'app_invoice'

class AppSale(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)  # AutoField?

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'app_sale'
```

I execute same code,

```
>>>sale = AppSale.objects.using('project1').all()
>>>sale
[<AppSale: AppSale object>]
>>>sale[0].invoice
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'AppSale' object has no attribute 'invoice'
```

How can I access invoice from sale in project2?

Comment: I collected project1 models using inspectdb command. It shows outputs models as <Appname><Modelname>. `AppSale` class is same as `Sale` class.

Comment: I added link for inspectdb command https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/django-admin/#inspectdb

Comment: Can u show the result of inspectb?

Comment: I'm fully aware of inspectdb. I've never encountered your situation, but what about the `Invoice` class in project2? Also the same? Can you show us the model for project2?

Comment: I have added classes.

Comment: I see no relation to Invoice in your AppSale

Comment: I figured one way. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `Invoice` model has `content_type` and `object_id`.
2. `content_type` is fk to `DjangoContentType` model. And `object_id` is positive number which is in fact id of `Sale` model.
3. `DjangoContentType` has attribute `id`, `model`, `name` and `app_label`.

Combining these 3 I got a wayto get the invoice for related sale,

```
sale = AppSale.objects.using('project1').all()
content = DjangoContentType.objects.using('project1').get(model='sale')
invoice = AppInvoice.objects.using('project1').filter(content_type=content,object_id=sale[0].id)
[<AppInvoice: AppInvoice object>]
```